# Who is waiting for a ManualResetEvent?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

Is there a simple way to check if any threads are waiting for a specific ManualResetEvent
object to be set?  It seems to me that the computer must be somehow keeping a queue of the
paused threads to restore later, so I'm just hoping to do the obvious and access
this list (just to check whether or not it is empty)...but I couldn't find a
method from looking at Microsoft's related Threading/WaitHandle/Monitor help pages.

Test code is below.  I'd simply like to replace the uglyWaiters counter.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace demo
{
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var gate = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        int uglyWaiters = 0;  // I want to stop using this variable and instead use something built into ManualResetEvent

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("a" + i);
                uglyWaiters++;
                gate.WaitOne();
                uglyWaiters--;
                Thread.Sleep(400);
            }
        }).Start();

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("b" + i);
                uglyWaiters++;
                gate.WaitOne();
                uglyWaiters--;
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }).Start();

        for (int count = 0; count < 15; count++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(uglyWaiters + " threads waiting at t=" + count*230 + "ms");
            gate.Set(); Thread.Sleep(30); gate.Reset();
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you need _number_ of waiting threads, or just check if _any_ threads waiting or not?

Comment: For my current need, I just want to know if any threads are waiting.  (But, I tried to make the point that the computer must be keeping track of all the waiting threads, so the number of threads might also be easily available...I'm of course curious about that too!)

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do this, and I have strong suspicion that if you need this - you are using `ManualResetEvent` in a wrong way.

Comment: I don't "need" it in the full sense, but sometimes for safety, you know it can be nice to confirm that no threads are waiting.